# is there a python trick to make kwargs.get a default method value if there is no key with that name exist?

Tags: python, class, keyword-argument

for Example if I have a code like this

```
class myClass:
    def a(n=100):
        print(n)


def myFunc(**kwargs):
     myClass.a(n = kwargs.get('val', 20))

myFunc()
```

I want it to use default argument (n=100) when there is no 'val' in kwargs. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, yes -- use `100` instead of `20` in your `kwargs.get` call.  The only other way is `if 'val' not in kwargs:`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think he means something that will automatically use the default value of the function he's calling.

Comment: if we don't know the default argument how can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `myClass.a()` with a kwargs dictionary. Then you can conditionally add the `n` element to that dictionary depending on whether your `kwargs` contains `val`.

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    args = {}
    if val in kwargs:
        args['n'] = kwargs['val']
    myClass.a(**args)
```